# How to retrieve text in Text Field from firebase when it is editing? - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I added an edit feature to my app, but the content of those posts is more than 100 words, when the text field shows up, it will be empty, I don't want that, I want to show the text field with old content, so they can edit or add content to the post, Is there any way I can retrieve the data from firebase directly to textField?

Comment: Post the code that you have written so we can work with it.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I will try Ibhrami's solution, and if it didn't work, I will update.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use `TextEditingController`

```
  final TextEditingController myTextController = new TextEditingController();
  ...
  ...
  this.myTextController.text = firestoreData ?? ''; //incase the data is null, it will be an empty string  
  ...
  ...
  TextField(
      controller: this.myTextController,
      ...
  ),
```

Comment: Thank you, I've been busy, so didn't check my stack, will try and update you.